# Choosing $f(x)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Is there any choice of the form $f(x,y)=f(x)f(y)$ which violate the condition below (one can also play with the integration range and make it depend on the variable which is remain to be integrated)?

$\int\left(\int\:f(x,y)\,dx\right)\,dy\,=\,\int\left(\int\:f(x,y)\,dy\right)\,dx$

Comment: You have the functions outside of the integrals?

Comment: No, I wrote exactly what I deal with.

Comment: Well your notation for these integrals is very confusing and hard to make sense of. It is difficult to understand what are the integral boundaries for each variables.
In particular, as far as I know, $\int_{-\infty}^x dx$ does not make sense.

Comment: @Surb No it is actually $\int_{-\infty}^xdy$

Answer (score -1):

Use the fundamental theorem of calculus and solve : $$\int_{-\infty}^t \bigg(\lim_{B\longrightarrow-\infty} F(y)-F(B)\bigg)dy\ne \int_{-\infty}^t (F(t)-F(y)) dy $$

These you can differentiate both sides and get

$$ (F(y)-\lim_{B\longrightarrow-\infty}F(B))\ne  F(t)-F(y) $$

You then consider the scenario where F(B) a) converges to some value, $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$, b) converges to 0, c)  if it diverges to $-\infty$ or $+\infty$.
Solve each case separately, and find how f(x) can give convergence of the integral.